# Mostrar todos os produtos de uma encomenda Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia!

Eu criei uma loja *online* , esse mesmo consiste um carrinho de compras.
Depois de o utilizador escolher todos os produtos, irá aparecer uma página "pagamento.php", antes disso ele insere na base de dados a **encomenda**, e todos os produtos associados à tal encomenda, por exemplo:

Esta é a encomenda 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nessa encomenda foram inseridos estes produtos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aqui tudo certo! 

O que eu pretendo é que na próxima página (pagamento.php) mostre o output da seguinte forma:

> Informações dos produtos comprados
>   `(id 27)`
>   Nome: Nars Contour Blush
>   Preço: 39.95€
>   Quantidade: 2
>
> `(id 87)`
>   Nome: Clarins
>  
>   Preço: 19.95€
>   Quantidade: 1

Porém da forma que eu fiz ele primeiro mostra todos os nomes, depois os preços e assim,... Aqui está uma parte do meu código para buscar e mostrar as informações

```
$procura=("SELECT encomenda.* , prod_encomenda.* , produtos.*
    from encomenda 
    join prod_encomenda on prod_encomenda.id_encomenda=encomenda.id_encomenda
    join produtos on produtos.id_produto = prod_encomenda.id_produto
    where encomenda.id_encomenda=(
    SELECT max(encomenda.id_encomenda) from encomenda)");


    $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$procura) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
    {
        $nome_produtoarray[] = $linha['nome_produto'];
        $preco_produtoarray[] = $linha['preco_produto'];
        $preco_total_produto = $linha['preco_total'];
        $quantidadearray[] = $linha['quantidade'];
    }

foreach ($nome_produtoarray as $produto) {
        echo "Nome do produto: ".$produto."<br>"; 
    }

    echo "<br><p style='background:black; color:white; padding:6px;'>Preço dos produtos comprados:</p>";

    foreach ($preco_produtoarray as $preco) {
        echo "Preço do produto: ".$preco."€<br>"; 
    }

    echo "<br><p style='background:black; color:white; padding:6px;'>Quantidade de cada produto:</p>";

    foreach ($quantidadearray as $quantidade) 
    {
        echo "Quantidade: ".$quantidade."<br>"; 
    }
```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer tudo dentro de apenas um `foreach`. Basta pegar os índices das outras arrays usando `=>`:

```
foreach ($nome_produtoarray as $i => $produto) {
                               ↑        ↑
                             índice   valor
```

Então ficaria:

```
foreach ($nome_produtoarray as $i => $produto) {
   echo "Nome do produto: ".$produto."<br>";
   echo "Preço do produto: ".$preco_produtoarray[$i]."€<br>";
   echo "Quantidade: ".$quantidadearray[$i]."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigada!